# asymptotic directions are perpendicular then the mean curvature is zero?

Tags: differential-geometry, minimal-surfaces

I just did exercise 7 from Manfredo's section 3.2, which says that if the mean curvature is zero at a non-planar point then the asymptotic directions are perpendicular.

My question is: Is the converse true? If the asymptotic directions are perpendicular then the mean curvature is zero? I tried to prove this and I couldn't, but I don't find a counter example either.

Comment: How did you try to prove it? Edit your post to include this.

Comment: I already got it, thank you